# Launch Chrome with a keyword search using Run command in Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, search

I can run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" superuser.com` to start Chrome and launch this particular website.

But instead of launching a website, I want to search for a keyword using the default search engine configured.

Note: I don't want to manually specify the search engine URL in Run command like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" www.google.com/search?q=hello+world`.

Is there any command line argument or some trick to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the thing you specify as the URL, doesn't really need to be a URL.

Then, you can easily do this:

```
chrome "? hello world"
```

The `?` will prevent the browser from thinking it's a path, without interferring in the search keywords (as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/314397/whats-the-whole-point-of-the-query-ctrl-e-in-chrome)).

Comment: @VarunAgw Glad to know that! Please, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

```
start chrome "? <what you want to search>"
```

This works if start chrome works.

Comment: This doesn’t really add anything to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, firefox does not take in "" as a search parameter it just opens ffox to the homepage.  Probably missing something here though.  A nice feature to run a quick query from the Address: toolbar

Comment: not related to the original question.