# Launch Chrome Keyword search via command line

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, search, chromium

I would like to launch Chrome and send a string to a specified search engine.

In Chrome, I have a number of different search engines, each having a "keyword" such that, with chrome open, I type the keyword, hit [space] or [tab] and then type a query. When I hit [enter] the omnibar uses the Search Engine associated with that keyword.

I have seen [Launch Chrome with a keyword search using Run command in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1070529/launch-chrome-with-a-keyword-search-using-run-command-in-windows), however, that is concerned with search terms, not keywords.

I know `chrome "google.com"` will launch and go to Google.com

I know `chrome "? google.com"` will use the default search engine to search the term "google.com"

So if my default search engine is Google.com but I have a keyword `ddg` to search DuckDuckGo, is there anything like `chrome -keyword "ddg" "dog biscuits"` to launch chrome and search DuckDuckGo for "dog biscuits"?

Comment: Did you find answer of your question?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything related to this [in the most extensive list of chrome flags/arguments that I could find](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

A workaround for your problem would be to use the search engine's request URL directly, for instance with Duckduckgo:

`chrome "duckduckgo.com/dog biscuits"`  or
`chrome "duckduckgo.com/?q=dog biscuits"`

Again, it is a workaround. It will work perfectly if you want to use this in a program. If you wanted to be able to quicly type a command via a terminal to get some results on a given search engine, I guess a batch/shell/python/whatever script could do the trick.