# How to select Chrome URL address bar by using shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [F6 vs Alt-D vs Ctrl-L (getting to the google chrome omnibar)](https://superuser.com/questions/283956/f6-vs-alt-d-vs-ctrl-l-getting-to-the-google-chrome-omnibar)

Is there a shortcut for Chrome to select address bar and start typing URL (key shortcut)?

Comment: See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/339686/48078), and this is obviously available in the [Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179&topic=25799&rd=1) too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`L`</kbd>, as well as in many other browsers. <kbd>`F6`</kbd> also works.

Comment: Command-L on Mac

Comment: Here's an overview of all keyboard shortcuts for Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Answer (score 9):

The Windows shortcut for this is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>; pretty much all browsers accept it including Chrome (even the Linux builds).

Chrome also accepts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Linux, or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Mac.