# Shortcut for Google search box

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Is there a short cut for Google search box as in the picture below in Google chrome?
Thank you.

The question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/283956/chromes-omnibar-shortcut-f6-vs-alt-d-vs-ctrl-l) is different with what I am asking.
What I want to find shortcut is the red box in the picture below not the address bar as in the link.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome's omnibar shortcut, F6 vs Alt-D vs Ctrl-L?](http://superuser.com/questions/283956/chromes-omnibar-shortcut-f6-vs-alt-d-vs-ctrl-l)

Comment: Hi, it is not. I meant the red box above not as the one above.

Comment: there is an extension in web store for google chrome named google search , try to isntall it and see if it can help

Comment: If you start typing on the page, it'll take you to the search-box by default (Just tested, using chromium based browser)

Comment: @RiA Latest Chrome here (version 61.0.3163.79 (Build oficial) (64 bits), Windows 10) and if I type on the page it doesn't take me to the search bar.

Comment: @RiA also does not work for me with 62.0.3202.75 (not that the browser version should have something to do with it I think). All extensions disabled.

Comment: Yes, I just checked. It doesn't work anymore on my end either. I suppose they removed the feature.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know when this happened, but today I was about to click the search bar and a little prompt appears near the bottom and says something to the effect of:

*press the <kbd>/</kbd> key to search*.

I did, and voila! I am able to start typing in the omnibox!

Thanks Google!

---

EDIT:

#### I found a screenshot:

[image]

Ironically, the shortcut doesn't work on the search homepage (`google.com`), only after you've done a search can you use that shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

Since this feature was very unfortunately removed by Google in July 2017, you need a browser extension to add it back. One that I find useful is: [Google Search Keyboard Shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-keyboard-sh/iobmefdldoplhmonnnkchglfdeepnfhd?hl=en). With this extension, you can just start typing and it will bring you back to the search box.

Comment: I think it's back. See my answer